# How can I replace the Greek symbols in an expression with their plain text names?

Tags: replacement, text, symbols

Suppose I have an expression with Greek symbols in it. How would I convert that expression to another expression where the Greek symbols have been replaces with their names in plain text? I've included a small example of what I mean in the picture. Does anybody know of an easy way to do this?

[image]

Comment: Related: [(25305)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25305/121)

Comment: Strongly related: [(a/135959)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/135959/280).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Extract all Greek letters from the documentation and make replacement rules:

```
nb = Get @ FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "Documentation", "English", "System", 
     "Tutorials", "LettersAndLetterLikeForms.nb"}];

letters = Cases[nb, StyleBox[s_String, "TR"] :> s, {-2}];

letters = DeleteCases[letters, "π" | "∈"];  (* reserved Symbols *)

names = StringTake[ToString @ FullForm @ #, {4, -3}] & /@ letters;

rules = MapThread[Symbol@# -> Symbol@ToLowerCase@#2 &, {letters, names}];
```

Then simply:

```
α x + β y /. rules
```

> ```
> alpha x + beta y
> ```

---

If any of the Symbols may already have assignments and you are working with held expressions use instead:

```
rulesHeld = MapThread[HoldPattern @@ MakeExpression@# :> 
   Evaluate[Unevaluated @@ MakeExpression@ToLowerCase@#2] &, {letters, names}];
```

---

In a comment [Oleksandr](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/312/oleksandr-r) posted an undocumented System function which could be used as follows:

```
names = Join @@ System`Private`NameCodeLookup @ ToCharacterCode @ letters;
```

---

Complete replacement rules in case anything goes wrong with the extraction:

```
{α->alpha,  ρ->rho, Ε->capitalepsilon,  Ψ->capitalpsi
β->beta,    ϱ->curlyrho,    Ζ->capitalzeta, Ω->capitalomega
γ->gamma,   σ->sigma,   Η->capitaleta,  Ϝ->capitaldigamma
δ->delta,   ς->finalsigma,  Θ->capitaltheta,    Ϟ->capitalkoppa
ϵ->epsilon, τ->tau, Ι->capitaliota, Ϛ->capitalstigma
ε->curlyepsilon,    υ->upsilon, Κ->capitalkappa,    Ϡ->capitalsampi
ζ->zeta,    ϕ->phi, Λ->capitallambda,   Σ->capitalsigma
η->eta, φ->curlyphi,    Μ->capitalmu,   Π->capitalpi
θ->theta,   χ->chi, Ν->capitalnu,   ϵ->epsilon
ϑ->curlytheta,  ψ->psi, Ξ->capitalxi,   μ->mu
ι->iota,    ω->omega,   Ο->capitalomicron,  Υ->capitalupsilon
κ->kappa,   ϝ->digamma, Π->capitalpi,   ς->finalsigma
ϰ->curlykappa,  ϟ->koppa,   Ρ->capitalrho,  ϝ->digamma
λ->lambda,  ϛ->stigma,  Σ->capitalsigma,    ϟ->koppa
μ->mu,  ϡ->sampi,   Τ->capitaltau,  ϛ->stigma
ν->nu,  Α->capitalalpha,    Υ->capitalupsilon,  ϡ->sampi
ξ->xi,  Β->capitalbeta, ϒ->curlycapitalupsilon, 
ο->omicron, Γ->capitalgamma,    Φ->capitalphi,  
ϖ->curlypi, Δ->capitaldelta,    Χ->capitalchi}
```

(Sorry for the formatting; I can't think of a nice way to paste this here.)

Comment: Slick! Thanks! Also, btw, it seems like `phi` and `curlyphi` got switched. I can't tell why.

Comment: @jmbejara They seem to be correct.  I suspect a font issue?  Try copying and pasting the rules into *Mathematica* -- they appear to work correctly for me.

Comment: You're right. It's a font thing (just on my end?). When I copy-past the last code block into *Mathematica*, everything is correct. However, in this post, they appear switched (for me).

Comment: @jmbejara In my browser both look like curly phi, but `\[CurlyPhi]` is larger.  I hadn't noticed before.

Comment: Ok. Good to know. Thanks!

Comment: `rules = MapThread[Symbol@# -> Symbol@StringReplacePart[ #2, ToLowerCase@Characters[#2][[1]], {1, 1}] &, {letters, names}];` will leave all but first letter in camel case.

Comment: @BobHanlon Good idea.  If one wants that this is shorter:  `MapThread[Symbol@# -> Symbol[ToLowerCase[#] <> ##2 & @@ Characters@#2] &, {letters, names}]`

Comment: `System\`Private\`NameCodeLookup@ToCharacterCode["αβγδ"] -> {"Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "Delta"}`

Comment: @Oleksandr Thanks!  I added it to the answer, with credit of course.

Comment: Also, `System\`Private\`CharacterNames[]` lists all the named characters and `FromCharacterCode@System\`Private\`NameCodeLookup@System\`Private\`CharacterNames[]` gives a string of them (i.e., `System\`Private\`NameCodeLookup` is a bidirectional function). Extracting the Greek ones may be more difficult. (I also found that `LetterQ` recognises Greek letters, but contrary to its documentation, `LetterCharacter` does not.)

Comment: `Flatten[StringSplit[Import["https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ListingOfNamedCharacters.html"],{"\n"," "}]]/.""->Nothing;
Select[%,StringMatchQ[#,"\\["~~__~~"]"]&]/."\\[RawPercent]"->Nothing;
Select[Quiet[ToString[ToExpression[#]]->StringTake[#,3;;-2]&/@%],!MemberQ[{"Null","$Failed"},#[[1]]]&]` extracts all listed named characters from the reference page and generates rules if the freestanding expression evaluates and is unequal Null.

Comment: The following code changes named characters like α to vAlpha. A syntax error will happen which I ignored. I removed the named characters that started with raw as they seemed to often cause issues. `rules = System`Private`CharacterNames[] // Select[Not[StringTake[#, 3] == "Raw"] &] // Map[ToExpression["\[" ~~ # ~~ "]"] ->  ToExpression["v" <> #] &] // Flatten // DeleteCases[HoldPattern[$Failed -> _]] // DeleteCases[HoldPattern[Null -> _]] // DeleteDuplicates // Quiet;`

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

I found a solution that is quicker than my previous answer in the case where the variables are Greek letters (like in the question by the original poster). The solution uses [`SpokenString`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SpokenString.html) and [`CharacterRange`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CharacterRange.html). The original answer below addresses the more general case of all named special characters.

```
(# -> ToExpression@ToLowerCase@SpokenString@# &) /@ 
 ToExpression /@ CharacterRange["α", "ω"]

(* {α -> alpha, β -> beta, γ -> gamma, δ -> 
  delta, ε -> curlyepsilon, ζ -> zeta, η -> 
  eta, θ -> theta, ι -> iota, κ -> 
  kappa, λ -> lambda, μ -> mu, ν -> nu, ξ -> 
  xi, ο -> omicron, π -> pi, ρ -> 
  rho, ς -> finalsigma, σ -> sigma, τ -> 
  tau, υ -> upsilon, φ -> curlyphi, χ -> 
  chi, ψ -> psi, ω -> omega} *)
```

---

## Previous answer

The following code defines replacement rules that change all named characters like α to vAlpha and € to vEuro.

### Code

```
rules = System`Private`CharacterNames[] // 
         Select[Not[StringTake[#, 3] == "Raw"] &] // 
        Map[ToExpression["\[" ~~ # ~~ "]"] -> 
           ToExpression["v" <> #] &] // Flatten // 
      DeleteCases[HoldPattern[$Failed -> _]] // 
     DeleteCases[HoldPattern[Null -> _]] // DeleteDuplicates // Quiet;

nameify[s_] := 
     s // ToString // Characters // ToExpression // ReplaceAll[rules] // 
        Map[ToString] // StringJoin // ToExpression
```

### Explanation

As mentioned in the comments, System`Private`CharacterNames[] can be used to list all named characters.

However, I did not get the mentioned System`Private`NameCodeLookup to work.

I removed the named characters that started with raw as they seemed to often cause issues.

A syntax error will still happen which I ignored.

The code:

```
rules = System`Private`CharacterNames[] // 
         Select[Not[StringTake[#, 3] == "Raw"] &] // 
        Map[ToExpression["\[" ~~ # ~~ "]"] -> 
           ToExpression["v" <> #] &] // Flatten // 
      DeleteCases[HoldPattern[$Failed -> _]] // 
     DeleteCases[HoldPattern[Null -> _]] // DeleteDuplicates // Quiet;
```

For variables with lowercase names, instead of `ToExpression["v" <> #]` use: `ToExpression@ToLowerCase[#]`

We may then define a function that replaces a symbol like
DΩ1 to Dcapitalomega1 :

```
nameify[s_] := 
 s // ToString // Characters // ToExpression // ReplaceAll[rules] // 
    Map[ToString] // StringJoin // ToExpression
```

test:

```
nameify[DΩ1]

(* Dcapitalomega1 *)
```