# What's purpose of function System`Private`LookupCodeByName and System`Private`LookupNameByCode

Tags: undocumented, character-encoding, internals, named-characters

These are useful function from their name.And they are [*kernel function*](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/133403/21532) since:

```
System`Private`HasAnyCodesQ /@ {System`Private`LookupCodeByName, 
  System`Private`LookupNameByCode}
```

> {True, True}

But how to use them?

Comment: Are you really going to eventually ask about all the undocumented functions?

Comment: @J.M. I just think they are makes sense maybe. :)

Comment: They do have `Private\`` in them...

Comment: But these turn out not be that interesting. One can do the same thing with top-level functions, pretty much as efficiently as needed. I think many of the internal functions are just auxiliary functions written for other higher-level functions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I tried random inputs until I got something to work. It looks like it has to do with character codes:

```
System`Private`LookupNameByCode[200]
```

> ```
> "CapitalEGrave"
> ```

And then we can plug in the reverse:

```
System`Private`LookupCodeByName["CapitalEGrave"]
```

> ```
> 200
> ```

---

Edit by yode as [J.M.'s comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/135958/whats-purpose-of-function-systemprivatelookupcodebyname-and-systemprivatelo#comment366843_135959)

```
Grid[DeleteCases[{#, FromCharacterCode[#], 
     System`Private`LookupNameByCode[#]} & /@ 
   Range[100, 174], {_, _, $Failed}], Frame -> All]
```

> [image: output]

Comment: So, a bit like `FromCharacterCode[]` and `ToCharacterCode[]`, but with the character names and not the characters themselves.

Comment: ...and they (`Lookup*`) fail on ASCII characters.

Comment: @MichaelE2 ... and also fail on such special characters as `\!` and `\(` etc.: ``System`Private`LookupNameByCode[ToCharacterCode["\!\(\)"]]``.