# Re-encode text file to use Mathematica's character name, like \[Alpha]

Tags: packages, text, conversion, character-encoding, named-characters

How can I re-encode a text file (or string) so that non-ASCII characters will be represented using *Mathematica*'s standard names?

For example, if the original contents of the file was

```
xαy
```

then the re-encoded file should contain

```
x\[Alpha]y
```

---

Using the [`CharacterEncoding`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CharacterEncoding.html) `"Mathematica7"` comes close, but it is too aggressive: it also encodes ASCII characters like `x` and `y`:

```
ExportString["xαy", "Text", CharacterEncoding -> "Mathematica7"]
(* "\\170\\[Alpha]\\171" *)
```

I do not want this. **Update:** *Looking more closely, this is probably not the purpose of the `"MathematicaN"` character encodings.*

I also do not want to change the contents of the file, only change its encoding. This means that re-wrapping lines, eliminating whitespace, changing new lines, etc. is not acceptable.

---

Why do I need this?  I want to take a package file that is UTF-8 encoded and make it platform independent. How such a file gets read by `Get` depends on `$CharacterEncoding`, which may differ between computers.

Comment: What is about saving it as `"Package"`?

Comment: `ExportString[xαy, "Package"]` returns a string with `x\[Alpha]y` as the last line. Isn't it what you need?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov But it also does other things, such as insert quotation marks, convert `\` to `\\`, convert any newline to `\n`, reformat for a certain width, etc. I do not want these.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Given my use case, I guess I could simply import the old package wrapped in `HoldComplete` (with a controlled `$CharacterEncoding`), then re-export it (both as `"Package"`).  But this also has undesirable side effects: it drops all comments and it destroys code formatting (making the code almost unreadable).  I would prefer to only touch non-ASCII characters, and simply replace them by their Mathematica-name.

Comment: Normally packages contain only ASCII characters. From where come non-ASCII characters?

Comment: According to [Docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/Package.html), `"Package"` (.m) is "Plain ASCII text format."

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov You can type anything in an `.m` file. I typed non-ASCII characters.  Others have done the same because on both OS X and Linux UTF-8 works just fine with Mathematica. On Windows, sometimes it does and sometimes it doesn't. It depends on the settings.  There are `.m` files around with non-ASCII encodings.   I do not want to go through the file and fix everything manually. I want Mathematica to do it for me.

Comment: Then probably replacement with escaped versions would solve this: `ExportString[StringReplace["xαy", "α" -> "\\[Alpha]"], "Text"]`?

Comment: Yes, but [the list of named characters](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ListingOfNamedCharacters.html) is long, and it is clear that Mathematica knows them, so why do I have to type in hundreds of replacement rules to make sure that nothing would ever get missed?

Comment: What may work is opening the `.m` file using the FE and re-saving it.  This can also be automated.

Comment: Could [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/135959/4346) be of any help?

Comment: @ChipHurst Absolutely. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it. ``fromCode[c_Integer] /; c < 160 := FromCharacterCode[c];
fromCode[c_Integer] := 
  "\\[" <> System`Private`LookupNameByCode[c] <> "]";

StringJoin@
  Map[fromCode]@
   ToCharacterCode@
    Import["myfile", "Text", CharacterEncoding -> "UTF-8"]``

Comment: Related: [(1137)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1137/121), [(25305)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25305/121), [(74047)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/74047/121)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based off information from [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/135959/4346) thread, the following should work.

```
fromCode[c_Integer] /; c < 160 := FromCharacterCode[c];

fromCode[c_Integer] := "\\[" <> System`Private`LookupNameByCode[c] <> "]";
```

Test:

```
Export["myfile", "x\[Alpha]y", "Text"];

StringJoin[fromCode /@ ToCharacterCode[
  Import["myfile", "Text", CharacterEncoding -> "UTF-8"]]]
```

> ```
> "x\\[Alpha]y"
> ```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a robust version of [`fromCode`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/144981/280) which uses only [well-documented](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SpecialCharacters-StringsAndCharacters.html#1663) functionality, and correctly handles extended-ASCII and Unicode characters with which the original version fails:

```
fromCode[c_Integer] /; c <= 127 := FromCharacterCode[c];
fromCode[c_Integer] := 
  StringTake[ToString[FromCharacterCode[c], InputForm, 
    CharacterEncoding -> "PrintableASCII"], {2, -2}];
```

Notes:

1. The [ASCII character set contains characters with codes up to 127 inclusively](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41198513/590388), so the upper bound is set to 127.
2. When importing as `"Text"` we don't have to specify `CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"` explicitly, [since](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/Text.html#1776349723)

   > `Import["file.txt"]` reads a text file, taking the character encoding to be `"UTF8"` by default.

Testing:

```
Export["myfile", "xαy\nLamé \[LongRightArrow] αβ+", "Text"];

StringJoin[fromCode /@ ToCharacterCode[Import["myfile", "Text"]]]
```

> ```
> "x\\[Alpha]y
> Lam\\[EAcute] \\[LongRightArrow] \\[Alpha]\\[Beta]+"
> ```

---

Another approach is to use `ExportAsASCII` function from [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/146404/280) answer which should be much more efficient:

```
ExportAsASCII["myfileInASCII", Import["myfile", "Text"]]
```

Answer (score 4):

For the particular use case I am interested in (i.e. replacing non-ASCII characters in package files), one can simply open the file (`.m` or `.wl`) with the Front End and re-save it.

This can also be automated:

```
NotebookSave@NotebookOpen["mypackage.m"] (* Warning: this overwrites the file! *)
```

This method does insert `(:: Package ::)` at the beginning of the file, and does require the system character encoding to be the same as that of the `.m` file.  It may also change the newline style (LF vs CR/LF).  But these are relatively minor inconveniences.

The code formatting (indentation, etc.) is preserved.

I verified that nothing else is changed by `diff`ing the end result with the original input file.