# Infix non-ASCII operator needs a space to be parsed correctly in a script

Tags: bugs, syntax, packages, custom-notation, parsing

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier and persisting through 11.1**

---

First off:

```
$Version
(* "11.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 28, 2016)" *)

$CharacterEncoding
(* "WindowsANSI" *)
```

I would like to use an unused operator to define a binary function, e.g `±` or `·`, as these are part of the Windows ANSI code page (i.e. [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)). Doing this in a Mathematica notebook is all well and good, but if I try to do it in a source file that I feed to `wolfram -script ...`, the parser acts up:

```
a_±b_:={a+b,a-b}
Print[5±3]
```

```
SetDelayed::write: Tag Times in _ (a_±b) is Protected.
```

So it seems this gets parsed as two tokens `a_±b` (i.e. a pattern named `a` with head `±b`, which is not a thing) and `_`. If I insert a space in front of the `±`, everything works fine:

```
a_ ±b_:={a+b,a-b}
Print[5±3]
```

```
{8, 2}
```

I'm seeing the exact same behaviour with `·`.

Is there a good reason why the first version isn't parsed correctly or is this a bug?

Comment: It is probably best to stick to ASCII in `.m` files, otherwise they will not be portable between platforms. I learned this the hard way.  You could use `\[PlusMinus]` instead. Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/144902/12  (I know that this is not an answer.)

Comment: @Szabolcs Well, I'm not actually using this in production code but for code golf, but even if I wasn't then before I start using `\[PlusMinus]` I'd rather go back to defining a simple function because I find this ASCII longhand notation very unreadable.

Comment: I would argue that this is just an encoding. If you use the front end as the editor, you see `±`.  But it encodes this as `\[PlusMinus]`.  This is comparable to how UTF-8 encodes some characters on 4 bytes instead of 1. But this probably won't be bought by whoever judges your code golf.

Comment: BTW I just tested this on a Mac, where the default is UTF8, and there is no problem at all with parsing `5±3`, no spaces.  What does `Print@Head[5±3]` output when you put it in a script?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood.  I see that it is a problem only with `Print@Head[a_±b_]`, which prints `Times` when there are no spaces.  Definitely a bug to be reported.

Comment: @Szabolcs Does that also happen with UTF-8 then?

Comment: Yes, `a_±b_` is misparsed. `5±3` is fine.

Comment: Works fine in Math8.0.4 on Win7x64. So, this bug was introduced in 9.0.

Comment: I reported the issue to Wolfram Support and it's been reproduced and confirmed on their end (and forwarded to the devs).